# Is it tough to make a robotic workshop of your own

Tags: irobot-create

I want to make a robotic workshop.. I recruited 10 members to work...  Please give some tips about robotic workshop

Comment: Related:  http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/how-do-robotics-startups-work

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to completely disagree with previous answers stated. Robotics consists of two major parts: 1.Hardware and 2.Software. Mechanical and  electrical are generally subclasses of hardware. Software is a subclass of, you guessed it, software. Software encompasses programming of course, however some argue that it also encompasses algorithm analysis and computational processing.

Nonetheless, the difficulty of starting a robotics workshop, as you call it, depends on the skills and backgrounds of the people you recruited. If everyone is a software engineer, you're going to have problems, the same applies for if everyone is a mechanical engineer. The hardest part of robotics comes from  understanding how all the encompassing disciplines and their respective principles come together to function in a single system. You have to be able to look at individual  subsystems and then understand how these subsystems interact with each other to create the main top-level system.

Anyway digressing from that tangent, if you are looking for a starting point look at arduino and at raspberry pi. The great thing is that they are open source, so you can look at other projects, make your own, and ask for help here and on their very active respective forums. Look at a website called seedstudio.com it has a large variety of arduino and raspberry pi compatible parts you can order and use for whatever you want.

As for programs, for 3d cad user solid works or autodesk inventor. For PCBs eagle or tinycad are good. For programming the arduino ide or visual studio are good. And there's a site called opensourcehardware.com that has all the tutorials on arduino programming and interfacing with digital electronics. I would definitely encourage you to look at those.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is tough if you don't have any knowledge on programming or electronic.

There are three parts related to Robotics: 
Mechanical part, Hardware part and Software part.

You should focus on one or more parts of them.

Usually programming is the key thing. Because you can buy existing equipment(mech or hw) instead of designing your own and build them but you have to program by yourself.

So if you really know nothing, buy some devices like Arduino and using them to teach MCU/EmbeddedSystem programming.

Advanced, try to design circuit yourself. Either breadboard or designing PCB using Eagle or Altium Designer.

More advanced and if possible, design the mechanical part by yourself. Design the  joint and structure by Solidworks and produce what you draw using 3d printer or other ways.

Comment: Yup i am studying software engineering

Comment: Thanx for the answer